# Are there other methods than emailing a verification link to verify account info?

Tags: email, email-validation, user-accounts

At the moment, we are sending an email address verification email each time someone signs up. This email has been causing a number of problems: people don't get it, they just don't click the link in the email or the email gets block by spam or some other method. We are working on resolving the spam issue, although I don't think it's possible to completely resolve it.

I'm wondering what other methods there might be for verifying and email address. Is there any other way to verify an email address without sending an email? Or is there another method of ensuring people aren't signing up with fake information?

Comment: Wouldn't it make things super easier for spammers if they could find out what email addresses are valid without even having to initially send email to those addresses?

Comment: @matt b Sorry, can you explain yourself a bit more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are other good methods, but sending an email and having them click a link is definitely the simplest and most accurate.

Answer (score 3):

A main feature to sending that email, is for the person to verify that it's actually them that requested it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to verify someone owns an email address is to have him use it.

As for verifying users don't enter fake information - not even sending an email can help. With so many disposable/temporary email services out there (like [GuerrillaMail](http://www.guerrillamail.com/)) , someone can fill up your form with false info, post a temp email address, log to that address and click the link in your email - manually or programatically.

You have to trust your users to come back for your content, and ignore spammers.

Answer (score 0):

strikeiron.com offers a paid web service to verify if an email exists without sending a message to that email. try it out here is the link: strick
http://www.strikeiron.com/Catalog/ProductDetail.aspx?pv=5.0.0&pn=Email+Verification